# some ownership issues with github hosting

Tags: github

*I know SO is not really the right place for anything related to legal, but I'm not really asking any legal advice ... just some hints&tips.*

I'll soon be starting a project (academia) which I'll probably keep at github (for some not-getting-into-that-now reasons). Free package. And once the project is done, I'll remove it (I'll keep it locally, I'll just delete it from github.com)

Keeping that in mind, I wanna know ... does github take any ownership in projects hosted on it ? Also, does it keep them after they're removed ? (Will it show somewhere on the net 6 months after I delete it from their site ?)

All experiences appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their [terms of service](http://help.github.com/terms/) say:

> All of your Content will be
>   immediately deleted from the Service
>   upon cancellation. This information
>   can not be recovered once your account
>   is cancelled.

and

> We claim no intellectual property
>   rights over the material you provide
>   to the Service. Your profile and
>   materials uploaded remain yours.
>   However, by setting your pages to be
>   viewed publicly, you agree to allow
>   others to view your Content. By
>   setting your repositories to be viewed
>   publicly, you agree to allow others to
>   view and fork your repositories.

and I agree with @mletterle that you can never be sure to fully recall something that you release "into the wild."

And you can get a [private plan](http://github.com/plans) starting at $7/mo.

Comment: I thought 'free' also offers some kind of private plan, but looks like i've misinterpreted them. $7/month I can live with ... thanks !

Comment: bitbucket offer free unlimited private repos

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want it on the internet forever, never make it publicly-accessible on the internet.

GitHub does offer premium accounts that include a number of private repositories, for a [monthly fee](https://github.com/plans), if you need that level of security.

Answer (score 1):

Someone can fork the project. If that happens, you cannot make them delete the code. Github is usually only meant for open source projects where the source will be shared to others, and others can collaborate.

Comment: I thought you can make your projects private as well ... (I could've misinterpreted something) ? No ?

Comment: Only if you get a payed subscription, otherwise it will be public.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can get an account with Unfuddle and create as many SVN and GIT repositories as you want, that will be private. Not only that, you get a nice Project management app with it too.